# Mercurial branch and hgtag version order

Tags: merge, mercurial, dvcs

I'm having an issue where merging branches is resulting in out-of-order entries in .hgtags. Is it important to fix this? For example:

e4b5decdb65523c16de6aaadd43ce8d5e236428d 1.310.0.1
1035a70a465aebf713ea97d216f0a65c001a8c77 1.311.0.0
fc15ee1aa4d03a41c2b3ce32146e6150349b372e 1.299.0.84
482392de6b7458a14d327b671c10509eadc92f44 1.299.0.85

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is absolutely not important.  Hashes aren't sequential and mercurial doesn't sort or parse your semver tag names.  Could be `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` for all mercurial cares.  As long as you don't have two entries for the same tag name you're golden.

Comment: It’s not that uncommon to have more than one entry for a single tag. You get this with `hg tag -f`. The latest one counts.